# How can I resubmit or cancel submission request of Google Data Studio partner Connector?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I have deployment id and I have submitted a Google Data Studio connector with invalid details and I want to correct and resubmit or cancel submission request of Google Data Studio partner Connector.

Answer (score 0):

Simply submit the connector again [here](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/pscc-requirements).